# Problems for deploy in heroku node.js app

Tags: node.js, heroku

I cant deploy in heroku my app something wrong with node.js , i tried to delete app , did again the app, npm install, install build packs, all what i saw for internet i did but i cant resolve the problem. The error is:

```
    -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
    -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
    -----> Node.js app detected
           
    -----> Creating runtime environment
           
           NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
           NODE_VERBOSE=false
           NODE_ENV=production
           NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
           
    -----> Installing binaries
           engines.node (package.json):  14.x
           engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
           
           Resolving node version 14.x...
           Downloading and installing node 14.16.1...
           Using default npm version: 6.14.12
           
    -----> Installing dependencies
           Installing node modules
           
           > react-redux-router@1.0.0 preinstall /tmp/build_94f5a392
           > npm set audit false
           
           
           > fsevents@1.2.13 install /tmp/build_94f5a392/node_modules/fsevents
           > node install.js
           
           
           Skipping 'fsevents' build as platform linux is not supported
           
           > node-sass@4.14.1 install /tmp/build_94f5a392/node_modules/node-sass
           > node scripts/install.js
           
           Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.14.1/linux-x64-83_binding.node
           Download complete
           Binary saved to /tmp/build_94f5a392/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-83/binding.node
           Caching binary to /tmp/npmcache.fQ3DD/_cacache/node-sass/4.14.1/linux-x64-83_binding.node
           
           > node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall /tmp/build_94f5a392/node_modules/node-sass
           > node scripts/build.js
           
           Binary found at /tmp/build_94f5a392/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-83/binding.node
           Testing binary
           Binary is fine
           
           > core-js@2.6.12 postinstall /tmp/build_94f5a392/node_modules/core-js
           > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
           
           added 1362 packages in 18.728s
           
    -----> Build
           Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts
           Running heroku-postbuild
           
           > react-redux-router@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_94f5a392
           > npm run build
           
           
           > react-redux-router@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_94f5a392
           > cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack/prod.config.js --progress --display-error-details --color
           
    clean-webpack-plugin: /tmp/build_94f5a392/dist has been removed.
        <s> [webpack.Progress] 70% building 443/443 modules 0 active 
        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
        npm ERR! errno 1
        npm ERR! react-redux-router@1.0.0 build: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack/prod.config.js --progress --display-error-details --color`
        npm ERR! Exit status 1
        npm ERR! 
        npm ERR! Failed at the react-redux-router@1.0.0 build script.
        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.fQ3DD/_logs/2021-04-21T16_54_17_773Z-debug.log
        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
        npm ERR! errno 1
        npm ERR! react-redux-router@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `npm run build`
        npm ERR! Exit status 1
        npm ERR! 
        npm ERR! Failed at the react-redux-router@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.fQ3DD/_logs/2021-04-21T16_54_17_803Z-debug.log
        -----> Build failed
               
               We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
               https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
               
               If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
               https://help.heroku.com/
               
               Love,
               Heroku
               
         !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
         !     Push failed
```

i tried all what i saw, my package.json:

```
 {
      "name": "react-redux-router",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "Basic skeleton codebase for React/Redux/Router applications.",
      "engines": {
        "node": "14.x"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "preinstall": "npm set audit false",
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack/dev.config.js --watch",
        "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack/prod.config.js --progress --display-error-details --color",
        "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build",
        "precommit": "eslint src",
        "prod": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
      },
```

what can i do?
Need more details?
Thanks for help

I instaled the buildpacks again and now th error changes, now is this:

```
 code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! react-redux-router@1.0.0 build: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack/prod.config.js --progress --display-error-details --color`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the react-redux-router@1.0.0 build script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.LI5Fz/_logs/2021-04-21T18_05_53_894Z-debug.log
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! react-redux-router@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `npm run build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the react-redux-router@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.LI5Fz/_logs/2021-04-21T18_05_53_921Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 31c1685dcd402b6a2bc433e60e53fd96f074132a
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 31c1685dcd402b6a2bc433e60e53fd96f074132a
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to funnybooks.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/funnybooks.git
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/funnybooks.git'
```

Comment: Are you able to run a build locally? --> `npm run build`

Comment: yes, nad this create new directory called dist. I tried to push again to heroku with this directory and the same bad result.

Comment: In my experience with heroku, heroku did the build script for me. Is that the same for you or are you adding the build/ folder to your repo?

Comment: I do not understand your question, I installed the build pack as the heroku website says, I have deployed other applications and it does not give me this problem in any of them, and I did exactly the same